# VBA code. Inside a button click inside a userform

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write the proper code for the button to "send' or "paste" or "select" whatever is in cell F9 and "send it" or "paste" or whatever to cell D9.

Below is part of the code inside the click button, the second line(last line) is the one I am having trouble with:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.cboDept3.Text 'set col
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Range("F9").Select 'set col
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use value rather than `.Select`

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.cboDept3.Text 'set col
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Range("F9").Value 'set col
```